# How can I center an image to the right of a navigation bar in html/css?

Tags: html, css

I'm completely new at coding so I apologize in advance for this question.
I'm trying to centrally align an image to the right of a fixed navigation menu.

Here's my code right now:

HTML:

```css
ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
     li {
        padding: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        background-color: #33b5e5;
        color: #ffffff;
       font-family: "Courier";
    }
    div.image{
           display: block;
        display: inline-block;
          float: left;
    }
```

```html
 <nav>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="sam/index.html">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="cv/index.html">cv</a></li>
            <li><a href="adventures/index.html">adventures</a></li>
            <li><a href="books/index.html">books</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog/index.html">blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="quotes/index.html">quotes</a></li>         
            <li><a href="contact/index.html">contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="image"><img src="vietnam.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="350" /></div>
```

I want the navigation menu to be fixed to the left, and the image to be to the right of the navigation menu but at the CENTER of the page. here's an image of what I have right now: [current homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukXMR.png). How can I put the image at the center of the page?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes I am, Pete. You got a better answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying the centre the whole lot then your `nav` and `div.image` should be `inline-block` to display them side by side. You should then put the lot in a wrapper which you can centre:

```css
section {text-align:center}
nav,
div.image {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:left;
}
 li {
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
   font-family: "Courier";
}
```

```html
<section>
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="sam/index.html">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="cv/index.html">cv</a></li>
        <li><a href="adventures/index.html">adventures</a></li>
        <li><a href="books/index.html">books</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog/index.html">blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="quotes/index.html">quotes</a></li>         
        <li><a href="contact/index.html">contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<div class="image"><img src="vietnam.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="350" /></div>
<section>
```

### Updated...

Now that I better understand what you are after (nav on left, image centered in remaining space on the right) it seems that [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is the simplest solution:

```css
section {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:left;
}
 li {
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
   font-family: "Courier";
}
```

```html
<section>
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="sam/index.html">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="cv/index.html">cv</a></li>
        <li><a href="adventures/index.html">adventures</a></li>
        <li><a href="books/index.html">books</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog/index.html">blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="quotes/index.html">quotes</a></li>         
        <li><a href="contact/index.html">contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<div class="image"><img src="vietnam.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="350" /></div>
<section>
```

### Attempt 3...

Based on your comments (fyi, you really should try harder to explain your requirements) it sounds like what you want is to centre the image regardless of the nav's position. In the following example I have used `margin:auto` to centre the `.image` and `position:absolute` to fix the nav in the top left. Now the image in centred but the nav may overlap it depending on the viewport width.

```css
nav {display:block; position:absolute;}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:left;
}
 li {
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
   font-family: "Courier";
}
.image {display:block; width:450px; margin:auto;}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="sam/index.html">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="cv/index.html">cv</a></li>
        <li><a href="adventures/index.html">adventures</a></li>
        <li><a href="books/index.html">books</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog/index.html">blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="quotes/index.html">quotes</a></li>         
        <li><a href="contact/index.html">contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<div class="image"><img src="vietnam.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="350" /></div>
```

Comment: Hey Pete. I don't want the "image centered in remaining space on the right". I want nav on left, image centered on the page. So technically there would be more "space" on the right than on the left of the image. Got a solution for that?

Comment: @Pete It seems to be working fine on my computer, but not on my iphone. On my computer, the image is centred, and on my iphone, it appears very much to the right of the center.

Answer (score 1):

you can use your div class if class is not work then use id for div like id="image"

```css
 
  
@media All and (max-width: 641px) {
   ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
 li {
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
   font-family: "Courier";
}
div.image{
 
      padding-top: 25%;
    margin-left: 16%;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 800px) {
 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
 li {
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
   font-family: "Courier";
}
div.image{
 
          padding-top: 23%;
    margin-left: 21%;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
 ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
 li {
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
   font-family: "Courier";
}
div.image{
       padding-top: 18%;
    margin-left: 24%;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px){
 
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
 li {
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
   font-family: "Courier";
}
div.image{
padding-top: 13%;
    margin-left: 30%;
}


}
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="sam/index.html">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="cv/index.html">cv</a></li>
        <li><a href="adventures/index.html">adventures</a></li>
        <li><a href="books/index.html">books</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog/index.html">blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="quotes/index.html">quotes</a></li>         
        <li><a href="contact/index.html">contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
<div class="image"><img src="vietnam.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="350" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

kindly check my codes i'll create for you

```
.image{
  display: block;
 text-align: center;
}

.image > img{
  background-color: red;
}
```

You can also check this link for your exact code http://codepen.io/myco27/pen/dNxWWK

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `img` element into `nav` and style `nav` with `display:flex, justify-content: space-between` See the code snippet

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
 li {
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: #33b5e5;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Courier";
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="sam/index.html">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="cv/index.html">cv</a></li>
        <li><a href="adventures/index.html">adventures</a></li>
        <li><a href="books/index.html">books</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog/index.html">blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="quotes/index.html">quotes</a></li>         
        <li><a href="contact/index.html">contact</a></li>
 </ul>
  <div class="image"><img src="vietnam.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="350" /></div>
</nav>
```